# CodeIgniter - I want to define array like config array in config.php file

Tags: codeigniter

I want to define my array like config array in config.php file. So I can access this array any where in my view.

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$my_array['app_admin_panel'] = '';
$my_array['app_admin_panel_assets'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the `simplest` way to define array as a `config item` is like below:

```
$config['myArray'] = array(
'name'=>'test',
'rank'=>22,
'division'=>'first');
```

Then `fetch` the `config item` using:

```
$data = $this->config->item('myArray');
print_r($data);// it prints your array you define in config file
echo $data['rank']; //prints 22
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$my_array['app_admin_panel'] = '';
$my_array['app_admin_panel_assets'] = '';
$config['my_array'] = $my_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your config files and declare array in this file. later you can put it on autoload .
so e.g `application/config/customconfig.php`

```
$Configarray = array();
$Configarray['key'] = "some value";
$config['configarray'] = $Configarray;
```

load this config file from your autoload.php